# How do I pass params on timer selector

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, core-location

```
  func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        guard let mostRecentLocation = locations.last else {
            return
        }

        print(mostRecentLocation.coordinate.latitude)
        print(mostRecentLocation.coordinate.longitude)        
        Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 60.0, target: self, selector: #selector(StartTestVC.sendDataToServer), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }

    func sendDataToServer (latitude: Double, longitude: Double) {
        SFUserManager.shared.uploadPULocation(latitude, longitude:longitude)
    }
```

I want send data to server every 1 minute. I am using Timer.scheduledTimer and setting selector. But how could I send lat/lng params to my function?

Comment: You can keep your location as class variable and send that

Comment: Yeah I know what about to send via selector?

Comment: @pmb you just have to get rid of the input arguments and use the class properties inside your function directly. See my answer below.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For sending the data with `Timer` you can use the `userInfo` parameter for pass the data.

Here is the sample by which you can get call of selector method and by that you can pass your location coordinate to it.

```
Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.5, target: self, selector:#selector(iGotCall(sender:)), userInfo: ["Name": "i am iOS guy"], repeats:true)
```

For handling that `userInfo` you need to go according to below.

```
func iGotCall(sender: Timer) {
    print((sender.userInfo)!)
}
```

for your case make sure your `didUpdateLocations` is called frequently.

Comment: iGotCall called every one second even I set 1 sec. why?

Comment: for one minute the timeInterval should be 60 so it's timeInterval: 60

Comment: yeah I know I set it 60 but it delayong 60 seconds and then calling IGotCall every 1 second

Comment: are you calling iGotCall from anywhere else?

Comment: no its not called

Comment: from where you are scheduling your timer in your question's code snippet?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150012/discussion-between-pmb-and-maddy).

Answer (score 1):

One way to make sure your `sendDataToServer` is always uploading the latest coordinates without inputting the coordinates to the function as input arguments would be to store the values in a scope, which can be accessed by the function and use those values inside the function.

Assuming you make `mostRecentLocation` a class property, you can use below code

```
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    guard let mostRecentLocation = locations.last else {
        return
    }   

    self.mostRecentLocation = mostRecentLocation
    Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 60.0, target: self, selector: #selector(StartTestVC.sendDataToServer), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}

func sendDataToServer() {
    SFUserManager.shared.uploadPULocation(self.mostRecentLocation.coordinate.latitude, longitude:self.mostRecentLocation.coordinate.longitude)
}
```

Comment: @Dnvid but sendDataToServer not being called at all

Comment: Did it work before the change? You didn't mention it not being called in your question. If it didn't work before either, is didUpdateLocations being called?

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly what the `userInfo` parameter is meant to be used for:

```
struct SendDataToServerData { //TODO: give me a better name
    let lastLocation: CLLocation
    // Add other stuff if necessary
}

func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    guard let mostRecentLocation = locations.last else { return }

    print(mostRecentLocation.coordinate.latitude)
    print(mostRecentLocation.coordinate.longitude)

    Timer.scheduledTimer(
        timeInterval: 60.0,
        target: self,
        selector: #selector(StartTestVC.sendDataToServer(timer:)),
        userInfo: SendDataToServerData(mostRecentLocation: mostRecentLocation),
        repeats: true
    )
}

// Only to be called by the timer
func sendDataToServerTimerFunc(timer: Timer) {
    let mostRecentLocation = timer.userInfo as! SendDataToServerData
    self.sendDataToServer(
        latitude: mostRecentLocation.latitude
        longitude: mostRecentLocation.longitude
    )
}

// Call this function for all other uses
func sendDataToServer(latitude: Double, longitude: Double) {
    SFUserManager.shared.uploadPULocation(latitude, longitude:longitude)
}
```

Comment: sendDataToServer called every one second even I set 1 sec. why?

Comment: @pmb huh? did you make a typo?

Comment: I copied your code did a little changes but sendDataToServer calling after 1 min but after that it started call every 1 second

Comment: @pmb Idk how you expect me to help you based on the little information you provided

Comment: is your code working for you? I am using exactly your code, but it not working. I just copied your code, and fixed the errors

Comment: @pmb Of course not, I didn't recreate an entire project just to run this

Comment: it was my mistake I called selector inside location update that's why it's not worked. Sorry man

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150015/discussion-between-alexander-and-pmb).